# Using underscore to check if array contains either of the two values

Tags: javascript, arrays, underscore.js

Using underscore's [_.contains](http://underscorejs.org/#contains), how can I check for either of the two values?

```
const valueToCheckFor = undefined || false; // I really thought this would work

const arr1 = [undefined, true, undefined]
_.contains(arr1, valueToCheckFor) => // true

const arr2 = [true, true, true]
_.contains(arr2, valueToCheckFor) => // false

const arr3 = [true, true, false]
_.contains(arr3, valueToCheckFor) => // false ???
```

**Expectation:**

Value should be **true** if either `false` or `undefined` is found in the array, instead I get `false` for `arr3`

Im not sure if `_.contains(arr, value)` can only use to check for one specific value in the array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This expression will only assign `false` to `valueToCheckFor`:

```js
const valueToCheckFor = undefined || false;

console.log(valueToCheckFor);
```

In addition `_.contains()` can't search for more then one value.

To search for more then one value, you need a method that can accept a predicate, such as `find`, `findIndex` or `some` (underscore or vanilla js).

This example uses [Array#some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) to iterate the array, since `some` returns `true` as soon as the predicate function returns `true`. The predicate uses [Array#includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) to check if the current value is one the values we are seeking.

```js
const containsMultipleValues = (arr, ...values) => // the values we want to search will be collected to the values array 
  arr.some(val => values.includes(val)); // check if any item in the arr is included in the values array

const arr1 = [undefined, true, undefined]
console.log(containsMultipleValues(arr1, false, undefined))

const arr2 = [true, true, true]
console.log(containsMultipleValues(arr2, false, undefined))

const arr3 = [true, true, false]
console.log(containsMultipleValues(arr3, false, undefined))
```

Comment: Interesting... what's `arr.some()`?

Comment: Yes, please? I have no idea

Comment: Sure. `arr.some()` iterates an array, and applies a predicate to each item. Whenever the predicate returns `true`, the iteration is done, and `some` returns `true`. If the predicate fails for all items, `some` returns `false`. The answer also includes links to the methods I've used.

Comment: Oh!! I thought that was a typo! I never know of `.some()` before. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some Cool!

Comment: Indeed. Not a typo :)

Answer (score 1):

In your example, valueToCheckFor will be evaluated to false, it won't hold both values.

What you need to do is check contains once for each value:

```js
const arr1 = [undefined, true, undefined]
console.log(_.contains(arr1, undefined) || _.contains(arr1, false)) // true

const arr2 = [true, true, true]
console.log(_.contains(arr2, undefined) || _.contains(arr2, false)) // false

const arr3 = [true, true, false]
console.log(_.contains(arr3, undefined) || _.contains(arr3, false)) // true
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may not need underscore, you can use `Array.prototype.includes()`

```
const arr1 = [undefined, true, undefined]
arr1.includes(undefined)  || arr1.includes(false) // true
```

Or a function

```
function IsUndefOrFalse(arr){
  return arr.includes(undefined)  || arr.includes(false)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use intersection to detect available matches present in array as follow:

```
var orgArray = [ { tags : ["a1"] }, 
                 { tags : ["a2"] },
                 { tags : ["c1"] } ];
var matches = orgArray.filter(function(val) {
   return _.intersection(['a1','c1'], val.tags).length > 0;
});
console.log(matches);
console.log(matches.length);
```